# Connect function from winsock in a QObject inherited class

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, winsock

i would like to use winsock functions (and not QTcpSocket or QUdpSocket) in my class. But my class inherits QObject, so connect() from QObject is in conflict with connect() from winsock2.h
How could i bypass this conflict, i'm searching for "Winsock2::connect()" or something like that, but i can't find. Thanks

Comment: The point of using a cross-platform framework is to ... have it work cross platform.

Comment: I have some bugs with  Q*Sockets ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `::connect` (for the winsock connect) and `this->connect` or `QObject::connect` for Qt's connect().